# How to implement pyobjc runConsoleEventLoop()?

Tags: python, cocoa, events, selector, pyobjc

For my own python project i need to use the *runConsoleEventLoop()* method instead of the *runEventLoop()* both located in *PyObjC* package.

The problem is that i do not understand the functioning of the *runConsoleEventLoop()* method and how to implement a custom function that will be started and looped inside the above method.

I have found that the *runConsoleEventLoop()* call a *runMode_beforeDate_* method which can be implemented with a *performSelector_target_argument_order_modes_* function, but I can not understand how to do it.

So I kindly ask if someone can write a full example on how to use this feature.

Thanks you all for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [autoreadme.py example](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/src/tip/pyobjc-core/Examples/Scripts/autoreadme.py?at=default) contains an example of how to use this function.

It is basically a helper function to run the NSRunLoop of the current thread with some additional functionality, such as better handling of python exceptions. You don't have to implement methods like runMode_beforeData_ yourself, those are part of the NSRunLoop API.